# Grep -v with two words and only full match

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I'm searching through a large file for all lines that DON'T contain X AND Y. So I tried this:

```
grep -v X bla.txt | grep -v Y
```

The problem is this removes all lines with either X or Y. I want to keep lines that have X but not Y and Y but not X. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex alternation for this:

```
grep -Ev 'X.*Y|Y.*X' file
```

Or even better is to use awk for this (to avoid repetition):

```
awk '!(/X/ && /Y/)' file
```

This awk will print lines only if both `X` and `Y` are not found in a line.